# Move physics animation on timeline without resimulating?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have a complicated physics simulation done, but I want move the entire simulation on the timeline.

Don't know how to do this without having to resimulate everything. Do not want to change how the baked physics look, just want to have it play the same animation at a different time.

Comment: Technically, you might be able to rename the cache files, I've been able to reverse cloth simulations that way.

Comment: One kindof hacky way would be to bake it to keyframes, then move the keyframes..

Comment: Render as is and then edit the final video so other video is played before?

Comment: @sambler I need to change only one thing happening in a large scene with other things going on at the same time. Editing the video is not possible in this situation.